# Gitlab - Reply by mail Not working

Tags: gitlab

In order to Configure `reply by email` ( For committing Issue From mail Reply )Trying to Configure using the following [Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/incoming_email.html#gmail)

Also, I use a **Gsuite Account**

`My Sample Configuration`

```
### Reply by email
###! Allow users to comment on issues and merge requests by replying to
###! notification emails.
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/reply_by_email.html
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_enabled'] = true

#### Incoming Email Address
####! The email address including the `%{key}` placeholder that will be replaced
####! to reference the item being replied to.
####! **The placeholder can be omitted but if present, it must appear in the
####!   "user" part of the address (before the `@`).**
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_address'] = "example+%{key}@gmail.com"

#### Email account username
####! **With third party providers, this is usually the full email address.**
####! **With self-hosted email servers, this is usually the user part of the
####!   email address.**
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_email'] = "example@gmail.com"
#### Email account password
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_password'] = "mypassword"

#### IMAP Settings
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_host'] = "imap.gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_port'] = 993
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_ssl'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_start_tls'] = false

#### Incoming Mailbox Settings
####! The mailbox where incoming mail will end up. Usually "inbox".
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_mailbox_name'] = "inbox"
####! The location where incoming mails will be logged.
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/mailroom"

# The IDLE command timeout.
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_idle_timeout'] = 60
```

**Configuration Verification**

`gitlab-rake gitlab:incoming_email:check`

```
Checking Incoming Email ...

Incoming Email: ... Checking Reply by email ...

IMAP server credentials are correct? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  An error occurred: Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) for [2404:6800:4003:c02::6d]:993
  Check that the information in config/gitlab.yml is correct
  For more information see:
  doc/administration/reply_by_email.md
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Init.d configured correctly? ... skipped
MailRoom running? ... skipped

Checking Reply by email ... Finished


Checking Incoming Email ... Finished
```

`My Gitlab Information`

```
Operating System - Centos 7
Edition - Gitlab CE
Version - GitLab 11.9.1
Installation Method - Omnibus package Installation
Access - Configured For Intranet users only.
```